# NaN error when multiplying

Tags: javascript, jquery, nan

I have this script to multiply two columns and display total in third. Here it is code:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#num1, #num2").on("keydown keyup", sum);
    function sum() {
    $("#total").val(Number($("#num1").val()) * Number($("#num2").val()));
    }
});
 </script>
```

And form:

```
<form method="POST" name="form1" action="" ">

<label>num1</label> 
<input name="num1" id="num1" type="text" value="SOMENUMBER" />

<label>num2</label>
<input type="text"   name="num2" id="num2" value="SOMENUMBER"/>

<label>total</label> 
<input type="text"  name="total" style="width: 40%;" id="total" readonly />

<button class="square" name="btn" type="submit">SOMEBUTTONNAME</button>

</form>
```

Comment: SOLVED by @Dave .Thank's. You can close this topic now. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3x `"` in HTML: `action="" "`.

This code prevents from not-numeric characters and calculate result on click button or change some number.

```js
function sum() {
  var num1 = $("#num1").val().replace(",",".");
  var num2 = $("#num2").val().replace(",",".");
  var decimals_prepare = (num1.indexOf(".") > -1) ? num1.split(".")[1].length : 0;
  
  return (!isNaN(num1) && !isNaN(num2)) ? $("#total").val((num1 * num2).toFixed(decimals_prepare)) : console.log("false");
}

$(function() {
  $("#num1, #num2").on("keydown keyup", sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" name="form1" action="">

  <label>num1</label>
  <input name="num1" id="num1" type="text" value="5" />

  <label>num2</label>
  <input type="text" name="num2" id="num2" value="2" />

  <label>total</label>
  <input type="text" name="total" style="width: 40%;" id="total" readonly />

  <button class="square" name="btn" type="submit" onclick="sum()">SOMEBUTTONNAME</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Worth mentioning NaN will appear until both fields contain a number?

Comment: Author can fix not-numeric values in `if` statement's

Comment: I think that was kinda the point of the question, dont you? Also, the exta `"` although wrong wont cause this problem (`NaN`)

Comment: @Jamiec extra " was typo. action=" " and not action=" " "

Comment: Updated answer @DraganSubasic

Comment: @Dave can you send me a message?

Comment: Write here what you want, stackoverflow.com not have PM's

Comment: @Dave work ok now. Thank you. But have problem with decimals on tota. For example: in first field i enter 1.200 and in the second i enter 3. Normal result will be 3.600 But i got only 3.6 in total field... Any thoughts?

Comment: @DraganSubasic check now, write 1,200 and second 3

Comment: @Dave you are fantastic. Works like a charm now. Thank you so much m8. :)

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have valid numbers first

```
function sum() { 

    var value1 = $("#num1").val();
    var value2 = $("#num2").val();

    if (isNaN(value1) || isNaN(value2){
        return;
    }

    $("#total").val(Number(value1) * Number(value2));
}
```

Comment: Or it might be better to not do the calculation on keypress but add a button and calculate when the button is clicked

Comment: Note that javascript has some oddness when testing isNaN for empty string or spaces. It treats it as zero so passes the isNaN test.....